# Google chrome address bar font size is very small

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

How to increase the google chrome address bar font size?
[image]

Comment: happens to me in Ubuntu MATE 22.04. Just to let you know it also happens in Brave and Firefox. I was concerned before, but its a minor issue - not freaking out about it. Maybe someday there will be a fix, but since its cross browser, I assume its a MATE issue and not a browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem since I installed chrome on ubuntu 22.04 I changed fonts on both OS and chrome, still no changes, it feels like I am the only one on Earth facing this issue, I have been looking for a solution fo a week, any help please? my eyes hurt, And I preferr to work with google to any other browser.. :(

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1302950)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gnome, you can change your scaling factor in Gnome-tweaks until you are happy with the new size.

Comment: didn't work. i changed to 2.0 no difference of change in the address bar font even after reload